# Центрирование div

Tags: html, css, margin

HTML:

```
<body>
<header class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header__inner">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="assets/cuda_logo.png" alt="Cuda">
            </div>

            <nav class="nav">
                <a class="nav__link" href="#">Home</a>
                <a class="nav__link" href="#">About</a>
                <a class="nav__link" href="#">Work</a>
                <a class="nav__link" href="#">Blog</a>
                <a class="nav__link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<div class="intro">
</div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
    font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1011px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Header 
================*/

.header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;

   padding: 58px;
}


.header__inner {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}


/* Nav 
================*/


.nav {
    display: flex;
    gap: 40px;
    
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;

    text-transform: uppercase;
}


.nav__link {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;

    transition: .1s linear;
}


.nav__link:hover {
    border-radius: 5px;

    background-color: #643A79;
}


.intro {
    height: 596px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #87509C;
}
```

Блок `.header__inner` нужно отцентрировать. У `.container` уже стоит `margin: 0 auto`, но это не помогает, также как и `display: flex`.

Comment: а зачем Вы хедеру задали position: absolute? от этого все проблемы - он у вас прилип к левому краю (сделайте ему какой-нибудь цветной бордер и посмотрите визуально на его поведение)

Comment: Да, действительно это решило проблему. Дело в том, что пытаюсь верстать сайт с задним фоном в виде цвета, при этом параллельно смотрю видео, где верстают сайт с задним фоном в виде изображения. Но теперь нужно красить header в такой же цвет, что и интро, и менять `height` у `.intro`., дабы оставить размер в 596px суммарно

Comment: Кстати говоря, я могу как-то header поверх .intro наложить? Я вроде поэтому и делал `position`

Comment: Честно говоря, не очень понял по описанию, что именно Вам нужно. Если покажете картинку, какой результат требуется, попробую подсказать, как лучше это сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Знать не знаю зачем вы поставили шапке абсолютное позиционирование.

Весь код:

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Header 
================*/

.header {
  padding: 58px;
}

.header__inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}


/* Nav 
================*/

.nav {
  display: flex;
  gap: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav__link {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: .1s linear;
}

.nav__link:hover {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #643A79;
}

.intro {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 596px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #87509C;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header__inner">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="assets/cuda_logo.png" alt="Cuda">
      </div>

      <nav class="nav">
        <a class="nav__link" href="#">Home</a>
        <a class="nav__link" href="#">About</a>
        <a class="nav__link" href="#">Work</a>
        <a class="nav__link" href="#">Blog</a>
        <a class="nav__link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="intro">
</div>
```

Либо же только та часть, которую я заменил:

```css
.header {
  padding: 58px;
}

.intro {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 596px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #87509C;
}
```